# .htaccess is not visible in /opt/lampp/htdocs

Tags: .htaccess

I have an `.htaccess` file saved in `/opt/lampp/htdocs`, the problem is, the file exists in the folder but I can't find it nor view it.

Anyone knows how I can view it?

Comment: In addition to answers you have been given, it's good to know, that files and folder beginning with a dot (.) are hidden, thus you have to enable "Show hidden files" by pressing Ctrl+H, or, as stated in answers, list them using `ls -a` in terminal.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple! I am such a newbie. Here it is

Go to the folder, and press CTRL + H, and there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to view the hidden files e.g. with `ls`:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs
ls -a
```